# Listing commands in powershell output file

Tags: powershell

Very new to scripting, and I try to use others' scripts.  I am running a PowerShell script that uses Get-Content to pull a list of commands from a file, executes the commands, and then outputs the results of the commands to a log file.  The script works per those specifications.  My issue is I wish for each command to be listed before their output in the log file.  If it is possible, how would this be accomplished in Powershell?

Comment: A few things: (1) We can't suggest code improvements without seeing the code you actually have; (2) You should be attempting this yourself first, as this is not a code requesting service; and (3) it is generally unwise to run scripts written by other people if you can't read them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a file like this:

```
Commands.txt
Get-Date
Get-Host | Select Version
Copy-item c:\file.txt -destination C:\temp\file.txt
```

If you'd like to display each command before running it, you'd run this:

```
$commands = Get-Content .\commands.txt 
ForEach ($command in $commands) {
write-output "Executing: $command"
Invoke-expression $command }
}
```

You'll get an output like this:

```
Executing: Get-Date

Thursday, August 13, 2015 10:32:02 AM
Executing: Get-Host | select Version

Version : 5.0.10240.16384

Executing: Copy-item c:\file.txt -destination C:\temp\file.txt -passthru

LastWriteTime : 8/13/2015 10:26:14 AM
Length        : 0
Name          : file.txt
```